# ¿Por que la pagina se recarga y no conserva sus datos, usando formulario?

Tags: javascript, html5, formularios

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario de **login** para iniciar sesión, pero al presionar Enter o clic en el `button` **iniciar**, la pagina da la apariencia de que se recarga y pierde sus datos, aparte de que me impide mostrar un mensaje directamente en el formulario.

solo se mantiene con un `alert()`

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function registrer() {
  console.log("prees registrer");
  window.location = 'gestionAlumnos.html'
}

var form = document.getElementById("formLogin");

function prueba() {


  var correo = form.elements[0].value;
  var contraseña = form.elements[1].value;
  login(correo, contraseña)
}

function login(correo, contraseña) {

  if (correo === "correo@example.com" && contraseña === "password") {
    alert("inicio sesión");
  } else {
    console.log("no funciono");
    var text = document.createElement("h1");
    text.nodeValue = "error de inicio de sisión";
    form.appendChild(text);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\citas.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

  <br><br>
  <!-- Formulario -->
  <div class="container">
    <form id="formLogin" class="col s12" style="background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);" onsubmit="prueba()">
      <div class=" center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">Inicia sesion</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="validate" />
          <label name="email" for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="contraseña" type="password" id="contraseña" class="validate" />
          <label name="contraseña" for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Resgistrase</a>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Iniciar
                    <i class="material-icons right">person</i>
                </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para evitar que el formulario recargue la página al ser enviado.

En este caso, tendrías que pasar `event` como parámetro, y dentro de la función poner `event.preventDefault()` y listo.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function registrer() {
  console.log("prees registrer");
  window.location = 'gestionAlumnos.html'
}

var form = document.getElementById("formLogin");

function prueba(event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  var correo = form.elements[0].value;
  var contraseña = form.elements[1].value;
  login(correo, contraseña)
}

function login(correo, contraseña) {

  if (correo === "correo@example.com" && contraseña === "password") {
    alert("inicio sesión");
  } else {
    console.log("no funciono");
    var text = document.createElement("h1");
    text.nodeValue = "error de inicio de sisión";
    form.appendChild(text);
  }
}
```

```html
  <!-- Formulario -->
  <div class="container">
    <form id="formLogin" class="col s12" style="background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);" onsubmit="prueba(event)">
      <div class=" center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">Inicia sesion</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="validate" />
          <label name="email" for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="contraseña" type="password" id="contraseña" class="validate" />
          <label name="contraseña" for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="button">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">Resgistrase</a>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Iniciar
                    <i class="material-icons right">person</i>
                </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Como te dijeron allá arriba, puedes usar el método prevent default que se encarga de cancelar el comportamiento por defecto del formulario, evitando que éste se recargue. 
Como cosa curiosa, puedes abreviar 'event' a sólo 'e' y seguirá funcionando:

```
 function prueba(e) {
   e.preventDefault();


  var correo = form.elements[0].value;
  var contraseña = form.elements[1].value;
  login(correo, contraseña)
}
```

Una vez hecho, esto el comportamiento del formulario cambiará y ya no se reiniciarán los valores que has introducido.

Comment: Explica bien por qué puede poner "e". Ahí le pones el nombre de parámetro, a fin de cuentas una variable. Se podría llamar "e" como se podría llamar "fulgencio". Yo soy partidario que los identificadores de las variables tengan un nombre comprensible y relacionado con lo que almacenan, así que antes de poner "e" dejaría "event" o incluso "evento".