# Problema al redirigir a otra página

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un curso de `MVC` donde el instructor usa métodos `$_GET` para mostrar  las páginas solicitadas, el instructor realiza un formulario de inicio de sesión y al ser correcto, este debería redirigir a la página que solicita.

En mi caso, nunca redirige, solo cambia el `URL`.

- Código `MVC`:

  1. **Controller:**

```php
class Controller
{

    #Interracion del usuario
    #------------------------------------------------------
    public function enlacesPaginasController()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['action']))
        {
            $enlaces = $_GET['action'];
        }

        $respuesta = EnlacesPaginas::enlacesPaginasModel($enlaces);

        include($respuesta);
    }

    public function ingresoUsuarioController()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['user']))
        {
            $datosController = array(
                "usuario" => $_POST['user'],
                "password" => $_POST['pass']
            );

            $respuesta = Datos::ingresoUsuarioModel($datosController);

            if($respuesta['usuario'] == $_POST['user'] && $respuesta['password'] == $_POST['pass'])
            {
                #AQUI ES DONDE DEBERIA REDIRIGIR
                header("location:index.php?action=producto");
            }
            else
            {
                header("location:index.php?action=fallo");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

2. **Model Enlaces:**

```php
class EnlacesPaginas
{
    public static function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel)
    {
        if($enlacesModel == 'producto')
        {
            $module = "views/modules/". $enlacesModel .".php";
        }

        return $module;
    }
}
```

- Antes de llenar el formulario el `url` se ve así:

[image: antes de realizar el formulario]

- Luego de llenar el formulario, enviar los datos, comprobar que son correctos, el `url` se ve así:

[image: luego de ingresar datos validos]

Nunca me redirige a la página que solicito.

Comment: Debes controlar que el formulario no se recargue, esto se hace con `preventDefault()`, como explica [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/316073/29967). Luego, convendría que implementes URLs amigables, esto se hace con unos sencillos pasos [explicados aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967). Si lo configuras así, el archivo `index.php` haría de controlador, y las URLs las escribirías así por ejemplo:  `proyectos/tienda_bebes/producto/1` que sería, digamos, solicitar el producto con id `1`.